# Bijectivity of sinx on the interval $[-\pi, \pi]$ to $[-1, 1]$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

how can I prove that sinx is a bijective map from the domain $[-\pi, \pi]$ to the co-domain $[-1,1]$. I had no problem proving that using the graphical representation of sinx, but rigorously could not.

Any help

Comment: Use cos(x) instead of sin(x).     Sin(-π)=sin(π)=0.   Thus it is not one to one function.

Comment: I am looking for a proof of its bijectivity, you are proposing the opposite

Comment: But $\cos(x)$ is an even function. Thus, $cos(x)=cos(-x)$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$. Therefore, $\cos(x)$ is not one to one in every interval of the form $[-x,x]$ with $x>0$.

Comment: @CarlosJiménez yes. [-pi, pi] is the interval of length 2π. So cos(x) is not an bijection from the given interval.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\sin$ is not a bijective map from $[-\pi, \pi]$ to $[-1, 1]$. If it was, then $\forall a,b \in [-\pi, \pi]$, $\sin(a) = \sin(b) \implies a = b$. However notice that $\sin(-\pi) = \sin(\pi) = 0$ and $-\pi \neq \pi$. Therefore we have a contradiction.

Restrict yourself to $[-\pi/2, \pi/2]$ and then you have bijectivity.

Comment: and how can I prove the bijectivity for   [−π/2,π/2]

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(x)=x/2$ from $[-π, π]$ to $[-π/2,π/2]$is a bijection.
Let $g(x)=sin x $ from $[-π/2,π/2]$ to $[-1,1]$ is a bijection.
Taking composition of these two function.

The required function is $h(x)=sin(x/2)$.

Comment: Sure, but that's a bijection of the map $\sin(x/2)$ not $\sin(x)$ as Derhham stated

Comment: But sin(x) is not one to one.

Comment: Exactly, I think the question is wrong as stated.

Comment: i found the statement of that question as it is stated in the book "how to think like a mathematician" by kevin Houston. But you right, the question is wrong as it stands